# Context path does not work when Tomcat is deployed in Docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat, download

We have a `Tomcat application` running in a `Docker container`.

The `Tomcat application` used to be deployed on a `virtual machine` and used `Context path` to provide facility to download files:

in web.xml

```
<Context docBase="/var/files/logs" path="/path_for_logs" />
```

Where the file to download was accessible by a link as such:

```
https://my.domain.com/path_for_logs/file_to_download
```

This worked very well.

But now we have deployed in a `Docker container` and the `Context path` no longer works.  The file is in the location as expected, but the download fails with

```
Failed - No file
```

The file is in the location in the container, so the Tomcat application can read/write to that location within the container.  But, the the Context path no longer appears to work to link to a file.

> Any guidance on how to remedy is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: @davidjmcclelland - We were unable to solve the context path and decided to just load file in byte array and return.

Comment: I had to resort to restarting the container to see changes. Not ideal.